# Experience Analytics doesn't display contact's interaction data created using xConnect Client API

Tags: xconnect, experience-analytics

We're migrating Google Analytics data and storing it in xDB. So, I'm creating some contacts through the xConnect client API and assigning those interaction data (that was tracked in Google Analytics) such as pages visited, channel etc as if they thy are tracked in Sitecore website. Contacts are getting created and are also shown in Experience profile. But it is not reflected in experience analytics. I think the reason is because xConnect stores data in the collection database and reports the same in Experience Profile whereas the experience analytics shows report from the reporting database.

Is there any way to sync those data so that I can see them in Experience Analytics as well? Is this the right way of approaching? Please help.

Comment: Are you adding the interaction data as web visits? EA will only report on web visit event types and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You could try following standard steps:

1. Deploy marketing definitions
2. Rebuild xDB Index
3. Rebuild reporting database. If this step, is already done with secondary reporting database configuration, then check the processing server health(logs) and configurations that takes care of aggregation and reporting database auto update.

Comment: We tried the above steps, the issue is not yet resolved. We think the contact and their interactions data is not submitted to the reporting database at all for it to be displayed in the Experience Analytics after rebuilding the reporting DB. So, is it possible to create a contact and submit the data to reporting DB using xConnect Client API?